# Spring change the binding target

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have 2 class  like this :

```
public class A {
    B b;
}

public class B {
    String id;
}
```

I have a form that modify my object A et its subs object :

it send

b.id=XXXXX

What I want to do is

```
a.setB(BDao.findbyId(b.id));
```

I want to look up in DB for the B object and set it on my object A instead of seting the id property of the A.b object

I can do it by hand in the controller after the automatic binding:

```
a.setB(bDao.findbyId(a.getB().getId));
```

But isn't it possible to do this with a Custome editor ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be possible.  You would have to write a custom init binder, which is basically a 'PropertyEditor', in which you can extend 'PropertyEditorSupport' class.  It would look something like:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  binder.registerCustomEditor(MyClass.class, new MyCustomePropertyEditor());
}
```

In which your `MyCustomePropertyEditor` would look something like:

```
public class MyCustomePropertyEditorextends PropertyEditorSupport {
    public void setAsText(String text) {
        MyClass mc = service.doSomethingToLookUpMyClass(text);
        setValue(mc);
    }
}
```

In the JSP/View, you will need to change your tags so they set you object reference, not the reference's id.  This has obviously been written off-the-cuff and by memory, so mileage might vary.  You may also want to consider looking into a custom validator as well, which you can also setup through the init binder, I believe.  Documentation is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html).

Comment: thanks this works, I would have liked a solution that doen't need to change the jsp